# monotonicity of a function with integer numbers

Tags: analysis, binomial-coefficients, monotone-functions

How to prove
\begin{equation}
f(x,N)=\frac{1-(1-\frac{x}{N})^{N}}{x}
\end{equation}
is a monotonically decreasing function of $x$ with $x \in [0, 1]$ and for any N=1,2,....

I plot the function for several $N$ which shows the function is monotonically decreasing function of $x$. How to prove it theoretically.

Comment: Hint: $f'(x) < 0$

Comment: If you are considering only $x$ to analyse if it decreases, then you really should write $f(x)$ instead of $f(x,N)$. Think in $N$ just as a fixed unknown natural number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand $(1-\frac{x}{N})^N = 1-N\frac{x}{N}+\frac{N(N-1)}{2}\frac{x^2}{N^2}-\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}\frac{x^3}{N^3}+O(x^4)$.
Then we have
$f(x,N)=1-\frac{(N-1)}{2}\frac{x}{N}+\frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}\frac{x^2}{N^2}-O(x^3)$
Taking the derivative of $f(x,N)$, we have
$f'(x,N)=-\frac{N-1}{2N}+\frac{2x(N-1)(N-2)}{3!N^2}-O(x^2)\leq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.